# How to pre-select radio buttons in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

When my model value is `true` then I want the radio buttons to be selected when loaded, but its happening the otherway around. All `false` models are getting selected. How do fix this.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DIYm4vBM3srdS61K6EPA?p=preview

```
angular.module('radioExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          $scope.kind = [{
            name: 'task',
            selected: false
          }, {
            name: 'bug',
            selected: false
          }, {
            name: 'other',
            selected: true
          }, {
            name: 'rfe',
            selected: false
          }]
          $scope.$watch('kind', function() {
            console.log('changed', JSON.stringify($scope.kind, null, 2))
          }, true)

        }
      ]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJs: How to set radio button checked based on model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530785/angularjs-how-to-set-radio-button-checked-based-on-model)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `ng-value` here is the doc for [angular radio](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)

```
<input type="radio" name="" id="" value="" ng-model="k.selected" ng-value="true" />
```

then, if the `ng-value` is `true` and the model value is also `true` then check box will checked

here is the [update Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Eoh1iyaDb9HLQyiYfwvd?p=preview)

Comment: yes this works! Is there a setting to toggle the selection? Because right now it it selects more than one radio button at once, I need to be able to select only one option a time

Comment: glad to help you , :) and if you want to select only one radio then you have to use same `model` for each radio buttons, in your case there are different models for each and every radio buttons, but you can do something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/pOzHeDvqz32qIxBGexvL?p=preview :)

Comment: Here, you deserve a cookie!

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="rempass" ng-model="rememberMe" ng-checked="rememberMeUserInfoCheck()" >  $scope.rememberMeUserInfoCheck=function() { return true; }
```

this works for me

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="rempass" ng-model="rememberMe" 
      ng-checked="rememberMeUserInfoCheck()"       
         >         
                                                        $scope.rememberMeUserInfoCheck=function()
 {
 return true;
 }         this works for me

Comment: sorry guys my mistake

Answer (score 3):

Add **ng-checked ="true"** to your radio input field

```
`<input type="radio" ng-model="modelName" name="radioName" value="value1" ng-checked="true">`
```

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me. Not ng-model nor ng-value.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the plunker [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UYyB0RJwqMJV8YPKrKP1?p=preview)

```
 <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <br />all 'false' radio buttons are selected when 'value' is used -------------
    <br />
    <div ng-repeat="k in kind">
      <input type="radio" name="" id="" value="" ng-model="!k.selected" value="k.selected" />{{k.name}}
    </div>
    <br />all radio buttons are selected when 'ng-value' is used -------------
    <br />
    <div ng-repeat="k in kind">
      <input type="radio" name="" id="" value="" ng-model="k.selected" ng-value="k.selected" />{{k.name}}
    </div>
</form>
```

you had it right.... just needed to add a ! so the model will take the opposite of the scope value... since you are using them for both I guess its wont hurt your code

Comment: Thanks for the response Jony

Answer (score 0):

### For those working with `FormGroup` and `FormControl`:

### In the template:

1. Add `formControlName = sameNameforAllRadioButtonsOfAChoice` as an attribute to your radio button `input` tags.
2. Also add `value = "true"` and `value = "false"` (you can also do it with numbers and strings, but I will continue with boolean).

### In the component:

1. Add the name, e.g. `sameNameforAllRadioButtonsOfAChoice`, to your FormGroup:

`myForm = new FormGroup({sameNameforAllRadioButtonsOfAChoice: new FormControl('false')})`

This sets the default value to `false`. In the FormControl, be careful to write it as a string!

### BONUS - If you need Validation:

1. `import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';`
2. `myForm = new FormGroup({sameNameforAllRadioButtonsOfAChoice: new FormControl('false', [Validators.required])})`